# Remove repeated field in json in android

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

I'm developing an android application, my network client is retrofit and I'm parsing network responses with `Gson`.

*Consider this JSON:*

```
{
    "response": {
        "typeB": {
            "data": {
                "type": "typeB",
                "id": "226131",
                "username": "something"
            }
        },

        "typeA": {
            "data": {
                "type": "typeA",
                "id": "226131",
                "address": "something"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

That data field is redundant. How can I remove that data using `Gson`?
I don't want to repeat data in `typeA.data.address`,
just `typeA.address`

Answer (score 0):

#### My Assumption regarding the Question:

I will assume you are trying to remove `Response.Type.data.Address` because it is redundant in `Response.Type` or in some other way.

#### Solution:

In this I am removing the address from `Type.Data` . I hope my assumption is correct.

```
 public  String removeAddress(String json) {
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject root = jsonParser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
    root = root.get("response").getAsJsonObject();
    Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> objectEntrySet = root.entrySet();

    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> object :
            objectEntrySet) {
        JsonObject type = object.getValue().getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject data = type.get("data").getAsJsonObject();

        data.remove("address");
        type.add("data", data);
    }

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    return gson.toJson(root);

}
```

Please do tell me if my assumption is wrong! Happy coding :)